# Angular 7 creating a card view and its detailed view in same page with a transition effect

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-transitions

I am a newbie in Angular7. I created a component in app.js and which shows a list of cards. what I want to build is on clicking the card view I need to show a detailed page with a transition effect.
is there any example which implements the same idea?
Please find a similar demo here [Card click and detailed](https://themes.materializecss.com/pages/demo)

Comment: You might want to change the tag angularjs to angular, angularjs (version 1) while angular (version 2-7). So that your question will be more relevant.

Comment: @AlokeT can u answer the question

Comment: Actually you are thinking on Pure CSS, it can be achieve let me check once. You are also use angular material right? So, which version of angular material you are currently working with.

Comment: is it possible for you to make a basic demo of cards in stackblitz?

Comment: @AlokeT I just started the project using the latest angular material library.
i want to know , what type of animation used in that demo and also is there any library for that. master/detailed view with transition effect

Comment: @Sibinfrancis I think here is the basic version of what you want to achieve using material + cdk, but need to focus on animation it's quite a bit challenge to do so, but not impossible. https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-overlay-step-5-jee9b1 is it you want ? then you can start from here.

Comment: @AlokeT Thanks for the reference.I think i can start from this demo.
need to make a connection from first component to second component. that is the image transition from first to second

Comment: you can ask any question regarding that, and also if you achieve that then please try to submit your own code here.

Comment: @AlokeT sure. Thanks a lot.I am searching for the transition part

Comment: @Sibinfrancis you are most welcome...happy coding... :D